# At which airports has the A380 landed?

Tags: airport, airbus-a380

I can't find a list anywhere (other than regular flights), but I am really interested, which airports have ever handled an A380 flight, including all one-time visits or emergency landings.

Answer (score 2):

Airbus [claims](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/passenger-aircraft/a380-family/airlines-destinations/airport-compatibility.html) that:

> The A380 is compatible with over 140 small and large airports for
>   regular service worldwide, and up to 400 airports when adding
>   diversion airports ...

The list of airlines operating A380s and their destinations [are listed here](https://www.routesonline.com/news/29/breaking-news/249703/where-does-the-airbus-a380-fly-q2-2018-network-update/).

I didn't find details about emergency landings.

Answer (score 0):

The [Aviation Herald](http://avherald.com) has a pretty thorough listing of any mechanical incidents that occur in commercial aviation.  Searching that site for incidents involving an A380 yields the following diversions to airports that do not normally see regular scheduled service:

- [Shannon](http://avherald.com/h?article=4b0978cc&opt=1)
- [Goose Bay](http://avherald.com/h?article=4af15205&opt=1)
- [Muscat](http://avherald.com/h?article=4a6c87a4&opt=1)
- [Perth](http://avherald.com/h?article=48b9f3c3&opt=1)
- [Colombo](http://avherald.com/h?article=48869588&opt=1)
- [Warsaw](http://avherald.com/h?article=4868e523&opt=1)
- [Baku](http://avherald.com/h?article=46e1dcdb/0001&opt=1) (after being informed that Ashgabat, which was closer, was "not suitable for A380s")
- [Ottawa](http://avherald.com/h?article=45083bf7&opt=1)
- [Jakarta](http://avherald.com/h?article=44f041b5&opt=1)
- [Hyderabad](http://avherald.com/h?article=444f5092&opt=1) (after being unable to land in Chennai due to runway length)
- [Honolulu](http://avherald.com/h?article=427e6e68&opt=1)
- [Nadi](http://avherald.com/h?article=4218d60e&opt=1)

Note that Aviation Herald does not routinely cover diversions due to weather or medical emergencies, so this is not a complete list of everywhere an A380 has ever been diverted to.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Airports can "technically" land an A380, all you need is the 3000 or so meters of runway required. Actually servicing them is another question. For example, Halifax Stanfield (CYHZ) has just enough runway length to put down an A380 assuming they have good weather and dry tarmac, but none of it's jet bridges are capable of reaching the cabin door. Apparently, the plan in place should they need to de-plane an A380 is to call Halifax Fire Department, and for them to take their cherry-pickers to get people down one at a time.